# How to guide induction to a different argument?

Tags: coq

Here is the solution to a problem that I did in Idris.

```
data Subseq : List a -> List a -> Type where
    Base : Subseq [] []
    There : Subseq seq l -> Subseq seq (x :: l)
    Here : Subseq seq l -> Subseq (x :: seq) (x :: l)

subseq_trans : Subseq a b -> Subseq b c -> Subseq a c
subseq_trans x Base = x
subseq_trans x (There z) = There (subseq_trans x z)
subseq_trans (There x) (Here z) = There (subseq_trans x z)
subseq_trans (Here x) (Here z) = Here (subseq_trans x z)
```

With Coq however I do not know how to prove this. This problem took me hours yesterday before I switched off autopilot and tried reasoning through it informally. Here is how far I've come.

```
Inductive subseq : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=
  | subseq_base : subseq [] []
  | subseq_there : forall seq l x, subseq seq l -> subseq seq (x :: l)
  | subseq_here : forall seq l x, subseq seq l -> subseq (x :: seq) (x :: l).

Theorem subseq_trans : forall l1 l2 l3,
  subseq l1 l2 -> subseq l2 l3 -> subseq l1 l3.
Proof.
intros.
induction H0.
- apply H.
- apply subseq_there, IHsubseq, H.
- inversion H.
  + apply subseq_there, IHsubseq, H3.
  +
```

```
1 subgoal
l1, seq : list nat
x : nat
H : subseq l1 (x :: seq)
l : list nat
H0 : subseq seq l
IHsubseq : subseq l1 seq -> subseq l1 l
seq0, l0 : list nat
x0 : nat
H3 : subseq seq0 seq
H2 : x0 :: seq0 = l1
H1 : x0 = x
H4 : l0 = seq
______________________________________(1/1)
subseq (x :: seq0) (x :: l)
```

In order to solve this last case, I really need to the inductive hypothesis to be `subseq seq0 seq -> subseq seq0 l`. That would allow me to produce the equivalent of the Idris proof. As it is I am stuck.

What should be done here?

Answer (score 4):

```
Theorem subseq_trans : forall l1 l2 l3,
  subseq l1 l2 -> subseq l2 l3 -> subseq l1 l3.
Proof.
intros.
generalize dependent l1.
induction H0.
- intros. apply H.
- intros. apply subseq_there, IHsubseq, H.
- intros. inversion H.
  + apply subseq_there, IHsubseq, H3.
  + apply subseq_here, IHsubseq, H3.
Qed.
```

I made a mistake. I did not think that generalizing `l1` would work here for some reason since it was tied up with `l2` in the other premise. With this bit of insight, the solution becomes straightforward.